# Illegal Argument Exception: Invalid message body when sending SMS

Tags: android, service, sms, alarm, forceclose

I'm attempting to create a service which sends a text message containing current wifi usage however I'm continually getting an error stating "Illegal Argument Exception: Invalid message body".

Any suggestions?

SOURCE:

```
public class Alarm extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onStart(intent, startId);


        String info = "";
        String sms = info;

        info += "Monthly Wifi Data Usage Amount:\t";
        info += ("\tReceived: " + TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() + " bytes / "
                + TrafficStats.getTotalRxPackets() + " packets\n");
        info += ("\tTransmitted: " + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()
                + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getTotalTxPackets() + " packets\n");

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage("9545555555", null, sms, null, null);    

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }

}
```

LOGCAT:

```
06-12 15:53:42.395: E/AndroidRuntime(29664): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 15:53:42.395: E/AndroidRuntime(29664): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.wifimonitor.Alarm@428fbb90 with Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.example.wifimonitor/.Alarm (has extras) }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid message body
06-12 15:53:42.395: E/AndroidRuntime(29664):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2549)
06-12 15:53:42.395: E/AndroidRuntime(29664):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:139)
06-12 15:53:42.395: E/AndroidRuntime(29664):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
06-12 15:53:42.395: E/AndroidRuntime(29664):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-12 15:53:42.395: E/AndroidRuntime(29664):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-12 15:53:42.395: E/AndroidRuntime(29664):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
06-12 15:53:42.395: E/AndroidRuntime(29664):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 15:53:42.395: E/AndroidRuntime(29664):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-12 15:53:42.395: E/AndroidRuntime(29664):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
06-12 15:53:42.395: E/AndroidRuntime(29664):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
06-12 15:53:42.395: E/AndroidRuntime(29664):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-12 15:53:42.395: E/AndroidRuntime(29664): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid message body
06-12 15:53:42.395: E/AndroidRuntime(29664):    at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:119)
06-12 15:53:42.395: E/AndroidRuntime(29664):    at com.example.wifimonitor.Alarm.onStart(Alarm.java:59)
06-12 15:53:42.395: E/AndroidRuntime(29664):    at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:450)
06-12 15:53:42.395: E/AndroidRuntime(29664):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2532)
06-12 15:53:42.395: E/AndroidRuntime(29664):    ... 10 more
```

EDIT AFTER FIRST RESPONSE:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onStart(intent, startId);

        String phoneNumber = "9545555555";
        String sms = "";
    //  String sms = info;

        sms += "Monthly Wifi Data Usage Amount:\t";
        sms += ("\tReceived: " + TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() + " bytes / "
                + TrafficStats.getTotalRxPackets() + " packets\n");
        sms += ("\tTransmitted: " + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()
                + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getTotalTxPackets() + " packets\n");

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage("9545555555", null, sms, null, null);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }

}
```

UPDATED LOGCAT (AFTER FIRST RESPONSE)

```
06-12 16:32:49.645: E/AndroidRuntime(31197): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 16:32:49.645: E/AndroidRuntime(31197): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.wifimonitor.Alarm@42cc0d10 with Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.example.wifimonitor/.Alarm (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-12 16:32:49.645: E/AndroidRuntime(31197):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2549)
06-12 16:32:49.645: E/AndroidRuntime(31197):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:139)
06-12 16:32:49.645: E/AndroidRuntime(31197):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
06-12 16:32:49.645: E/AndroidRuntime(31197):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-12 16:32:49.645: E/AndroidRuntime(31197):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-12 16:32:49.645: E/AndroidRuntime(31197):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
06-12 16:32:49.645: E/AndroidRuntime(31197):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 16:32:49.645: E/AndroidRuntime(31197):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-12 16:32:49.645: E/AndroidRuntime(31197):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
06-12 16:32:49.645: E/AndroidRuntime(31197):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
06-12 16:32:49.645: E/AndroidRuntime(31197):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-12 16:32:49.645: E/AndroidRuntime(31197): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-12 16:32:49.645: E/AndroidRuntime(31197):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1431)
06-12 16:32:49.645: E/AndroidRuntime(31197):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
06-12 16:32:49.645: E/AndroidRuntime(31197):    at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendText(ISms.java:714)
06-12 16:32:49.645: E/AndroidRuntime(31197):    at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:203)
06-12 16:32:49.645: E/AndroidRuntime(31197):    at com.example.wifimonitor.Alarm.onStart(Alarm.java:44)
06-12 16:32:49.645: E/AndroidRuntime(31197):    at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:450)
06-12 16:32:49.645: E/AndroidRuntime(31197):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2532)
06-12 16:32:49.645: E/AndroidRuntime(31197):    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got that error due to an empty message.

Here it is:

```
    String info = "";
    String sms = info;
```

After the below code, the `info` and `sms` are the same. But after you perform this operation:

```
    info += "Monthly Wifi Data Usage Amount:\t";
```

a new String is created and assigned to `info`, so `info` and `sms` are not the same anymore. The `sms` is still empty, and thats why you got IllegalArgumentException.

Just remove `info` in your code and only use the `sms` variable. You can also use 
[StringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Comment: I attempted the suggested method (I added updated source code above) but now I'm ending up with a null pointer exception (thank you for your help BTW!)

Comment: @user2478682 Probably the sms message is too big. Try to use smaller to check it.